# C Array Changing Location When Assigned Value

Tags: c, pointers

I have an `uin16_t` array that I am trying to initialize all values to zero, an interesting thing happens when I reach array index 4. The garbage value in there is 58248, I try and set the value to 0 and it changes the memory address, interestingly by 58248.

Here is an example of what I am doing.

I have a struct declare in my header:

```
typedef struct my_struct
{
    //various struct members
} my_struct;   

typedef union my_struct_union 
{
    my_struct struct_instance;
    uint16_t struct_overlay[6];
} my_struct_union

extern my_struct_union *struct_pointer;
extern my_struct struct_instance;
```

In my source file I have this:

```
my_struct_union *struct_pointer;
my_struct struct_instance;

void init_struct()
{
    struct_pointer = (my_struct_union *)&struct_instance;

    for(uint16_t indx = 0; indx < 6; indx++)
    {
        printf("indx: %d", indx);
        printf("address: %d", &struct_pointer->struct_overlay[indx]);
        printf("value: %d", struct_pointer->struct_overlay[indx]);

        struct_pointer->struct_overlay[indx] = 0;

        printf("address: %d", &struct_pointer->struct_overlay[indx]);
        printf("value: %d", struct_pointer->struct_overlay[indx]);
    }
```

Output looks as expected until index 4:

```
indx: 3
address: 6415246
value: 0
address: 6415246
value: 0
indx: 4
address: 6415248
value 58248
address: 6357000
```

Here a seg fault occurs. Interestingly the memory address changes by the same amount as the garbage value that is initially in that array index. I am stumped. I do this similar thing in several other places with no issue at all.

Comment: Use `%p` to print pointers, not `%d`.

Comment: It doesn't feel like it would take much work to convert this into a [mre]. Then we could all try running it.

Comment: is the question, why are you getting a segfault?

Comment: expanding on [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s comment, need also to use `%hd` for shorts.

Comment: @CarloArenas: You do not need to use `%hd` for `short` in printing. A `short` value is automatically promoted to `int`, and `%d` is fine for that. `%hd` may be needed in `scanf`.

Comment: `uint16_t struct_overlay[6]` Don't use magic numbers. What's 6? Why 6? How anyone reading the code could verify that 6 is right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `my_struct` is smaller than `4 * sizeof(uint16_t)`.  The address `&struct_instance` only points to enough memory for `my_struct`. When `indx` reaches `4`

```
struct_pointer->struct_overlay[indx] = 0;
```

will write outside the bounds of the structure, causing undefind behavior.

If you want memory that's big enough for both the array and the structure, you need to declare the variable to be the `union` type, not one of the member types.

```
my_struct_union struct_instance;
```

Comment: Here is a facepalm moment...of course. Thank you sir.

Comment: Weird part is I have some similar cases elsewhere and the struct is smaller as well and it works fine. Strange.

Comment: It's undefined behavior, anything can happen. Sometimes it causes an error, sometimes it doesn't. It depends on what happens to be in the memory after the structure.

Comment: The structure might have enough padding that the overflow doesn't affect anything.